# Would a GET request work? (JS)

Tags: jquery

Let's say we have an external page, called page `a`.

We know this about page `a`:

- When a visitor visits the page/site, it triggers a log function at server side, that logs the visit of the user.
- it uses the log to create a list of visits.
- when visited, it redirects back to site `B`

Question:

Is there a way for site `B`, a site maintained by me, to trigger that log function on site `a` without redirecting my visitor to page `a` ?

If so, would a Javascript based GET request possibly trigger the same function on site `A`, because `A` believes it's a visiting user?

OR:

is there a way to redirect the user, or make the trigger without letting the user know?

Comment: No, you can't `log` something if you don't have a `JavaScript` engine running, which is usually found in browsers. As for your question, what do you mean by `GET request`? You can only send requests to the server, not directly to the browser. The server will then send the response to the browser. Why would you need a request at all? Can't you just `console.log('a')` directly?

Comment: With that, i mean to send a get request to a url.
will the server on that url, detect this , like normally and log the visit, when it would log the visit in a normal visit to the url?

Comment: @maria If you try to send a request to the server from the browser to log something, than anyone could send requests to that specific URL trying to seem like a `legit user`, assuming they know about this mechanism. Your question is not clear enough.

Comment: There's no way to tell without knowing how the logging is set up. The server might try to validate the request, or it might not. In general it's almost impossible to prevent "fake" requests from a legitimate user, and it's almost impossible to make fake requests on behalf of another user if the server is set up correctly to prevent it.

Comment: You'll likely get a cross-domain / same origin problem if you try to do this from javascript.

Comment: Can you ask the owner of `a` if they have a logging api you can call?   Or are you trying to spoof unique visitors to make your site appear to have more visitors than it does?

Comment: op: @freedomn-m , im afraid not, its a blogging website. so they dont. i just want to make the user be logged there too. to appear on the stats.

Comment: @freedomn-m That was not in the original question, look at the edit history and see how the initial question looked like.

Comment: @Cristy the text of the original implies server-side logging to me... *but* it's only tagged `jquery` - which would obviously lead to console.log.  I'll remove my comment.

Comment: @Maria have you *tried* making a GET request?  It's only 1 line of code... do you get an error? (check browser console)

Comment: @maria, Details given by you is not adequate to give an exact answer. 1) Are you first visit site B url or you just visit A url? 2) Are there any logging pages or user inputs getting by site A? Anyway, if the site B is yours, you can use a php or asp server side script crawler  (cURL) to visit site A. Since you are trying to do it silently, use ajax to execute your server side script. Make sure you have set all relevant headers for the crawler.